# React TransitionGroup componentWillLeave does nothing

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I want to animate my loading screen using React TransitionGroup, so far I replaced the `componentDidMount()` lifecycle with `componentWillAppear()`, which works perfectly fine.

So now I'm guessing whenever my component is about to be unmounted, `componentWillLeave()` gets called before right? This is not the case..

There are some questions on StackOverflow about `componentWillLeave` and the `TransitionGroup` lifecycle but nothing seems to answer my question, and some are related to bugs which should have been patched in 0.14 I believe. I already tried a lot of things and logged a lot to the console but nothing happens.

Here is a part of my `LoadingScreen` component:

```
'use strict';

import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import BaseComponent from './BaseComponent.js';

let TweenMax = require('gsap');

export default class LoadingScreen extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
    }
    componentWillAppear(callback) {
        this._animateIn(callback);
    }
    componentWillLeave(callback) {
        this._animateOut(callback);
    }
    _animateIn(callback) {
        let node = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this);
        TweenMax.to(node, 0.7, {ease: Power2.easeInOut, opacity: 1, y: -75}).eventCallback('onComplete', callback);     
    }
    _animateOut(callback) {
        console.log('here');
        let node = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this);
        TweenMax.to(node, 0.5, {opacity: 0, x: -75}).eventCallback('onComplete', callback);
    }

    render() {  
     // Render stuff...
    }
```

And for your info, the render function of the parent component (it makes use of a FirstChild component so that I can use an expression):

```
render () {
    return  <TransitionGroup component={FirstChild}>
            {this.state.isLoading ? <LoadingScreen error={this.state.hasError}/> : <VRScene images={this.state.images}/>}
            </TransitionGroup>
    }
```

I'm guessing it has something to do with the callbacks because the [docs](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/animation.html#low-level-api-reacttransitiongroup) state:

> It will block other animations from occurring until callback is called. It is only called on the initial render of a TransitionGroup.

Do I call these recursively? Am I doing something wrong here? Or is this another bug?

Some insight would be great :)

TIA!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to provide an unique **key** for all children inside TransitionGroup. Otherwise React will not be able to determine which children have entered or left.

```
{this.state.isLoading ? 
             <LoadingScreen key="loader" error={this.state.hasError}/> :
             <VRScene key="VRScene" images={this.state.images}/>
}
```

[example with keys -> Works](http://jsfiddle.net/jwm6k66c/557/)

[example without keys -> Does not work](http://jsfiddle.net/jwm6k66c/558/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I did miss that, however, now my console logs this error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'componentDidLeave' of undefined`. And this error also appears in your examples... Maybe this is a bug?

Comment: There was an extra callback which I forgot to remove when I added your TweenMax transitions(which already call the callback function on complete), the examples are fixed now :-P

Comment: Ahh okay, well, I removed it also, and I tried copying your exact code but still returns me the same error. My keys are different so I don't understand. Also, you're using `componentWillEnter()` instead of `componentWillAppear()`, but `componentWillEnter()` also doesnt work for me..

Comment: You can try to remove "component={FirstChild}" since its not necessary and check that you are importing require('react-addons-transition-group') instead of require('react-addons-css-transition-group')

Comment: I removed the Firstchild component, I was convinced I needed it so that I can use an expression in the return statement. It's working now! Thanks a lot :)!